# ng-click function using $index as parameter throws Unexpected token error

Tags: angularjs

So I ma trying to loop through an array and create an list item for each object in it.

However when then adding an ng-click to that item i get the following error, even though the code prints out correctly.

```
Syntax Error: Token '$index' is unexpected, expecting [:]
```

I have the following code:

```
<body ng-controller="VideoController as VidCtrl">

<div class="row" id="grid">
    <div ng-repeat="array in videos" ng-show="VidCtrl.isActive({{$index}})">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
            <li ng-repeat="video in array" ng-click="VidCtrl.setVideo({{$index}})">
                <img src="{{video.image}}">

                <div>
                    <h5>{{video.title}}</h5>
                    <p>{{video.ingress}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li ng-class="{'current':isActive($index)}" ng-repeat="array in videos"><a ng-click="VidCtrl.setPanel($index)" href="#">{{$index + 1}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And This is my js:

```
var videos = [];
var activeVideo = null;

var app = angular.module('webb-tvApp', []);

app.controller('VideoController', function($scope){
    $scope.videos = videos;

    this.activePanel = 0;

    this.setPanel = function(val){
        this.activePanel = val;
    }

    this.isActive = function(val){
        return this.activePanel === val;
    }

    this.setVideo = function(vidIndex){
        console.log(videos[this.activePanel][vidIndex]);
    }
});
```

The videos array has the following structure.

```
var videos = [
    [
        {
            image: "foo",
            title: "bar",
            ingress: "foobar",
        },
        {},
        {}
    ],
    [
        {},
        {},
    ]
]
```

I am new to angular so go easy on me.

Comment: I see `VidCtrl.isActive({{$index}})`, `VidCtrl.setVideo({{$index}})` and `VidCtrl.setPanel($index)`. Why did you decide to use different syntax for the same thing in different places? And as some answers already pointed out, two of them is wrong and one of them is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using these directives you can use the variables without interpolation `{{}}`. Additionally, you can use `ng-src` with your images instead of using `src`.

```
<body ng-controller="VideoController as VidCtrl">

<div class="row" id="grid">
    <div ng-repeat="array in videos" ng-show="VidCtrl.isActive($index)">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
            <li ng-repeat="video in array" ng-click="VidCtrl.setVideo($index)">
                <img ng-src="{{video.image}}">

                <div>
                    <h5>{{video.title}}</h5>
                    <p>{{video.ingress}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li ng-class="{'current':isActive($index)}" ng-repeat="array in videos"><a ng-click="VidCtrl.setPanel($index)" href="#">{{$index + 1}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: aah, well stupid me thought that since the actual markup (dev tools) show the $index it would be wrong. Thanks, will accept this answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

Few things I noticed:

Remove interpolation from inside `ng-show` and `ng-click`

```
<div ... ng-show="VidCtrl.isActive($index)">
    ...
        <li ... ng-click="VidCtrl.setVideo($index)">
```

And replace `src` with `ng-src`

```
<img ng-src="{{video.image}}">
```